# Wifi not working on Thinkpad T460

Tags: 16.04, wireless, lenovo, thinkpad, intel-wireless

I just partitioned my windows machine and installed a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 on the partition with dual boot.

Unfortunately, the wifi doesn't seem to work - no networks are visible even though I'm in range of my home wifi. Also, I don't have access to a wired connection.

I'm 100% noob, but trying what I can. After some googling I found [this link](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) for linux support for wireless adapters and I figured I might need to install additional drivers? So I downloaded the driver from that link, which they said I could just put in `/lib/firmware`, which I proceeded to do...

Doing `dmesg`, I see there's a bunch of ugly errors:

```
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)
[    0.102148] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.224789] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin    (v1.26)
[    3.514413] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[   10.833905] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-33.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833919] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-32.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833928] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-31.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833937] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833946] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833954] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833962] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-27.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833970] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833978] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833986] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.833995] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.834003] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[   10.834005] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[   10.834012] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

Doing `lshw`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 3a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f1000000-f1001fff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 1f.6
   bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
   logical name: enp0s31f6
   version: 21
   serial: c8:5b:76:b1:32:d0
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:122 memory:f1100000-f111ffff
```

I imagine the `UNCLAIMED` there means something is going wrong with talking to the wireless device?

Doing `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If there's anything else I can try, please holler at me in the comments! (I need to reboot into Ubuntu every time I want to try something, and write text to a flash drive...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please download this package onto the flash drive: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.169.3_all.deb Reboot into Ubuntu and drag and drop the package to your desktop. Then open a terminal and do:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg  -i linux-firmware*.deb
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Is your wireless working now? It may take a reboot.

Comment: Speaking to you from my fresh new linux machine... It worked! Man I love this place. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue on ubuntu and kali linux, install the firmware-iwlwifi
by running the following commands:

1. sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
2. sudo reboot now