# I have no connectivity with wifi or Ethernet

Tags: networking

I had a problem with Wifi connectivity that I thought was to do with the Realtek Network hardware on my HP laptop so I tried some of the fixes online and ended up with no connectivity at all.

I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (using a usb connection to my phone) hoping that would resolve the problem but it hasn't
My Ethernet controllers show as unclaimed

lshw -C Network

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0504000-c0504fff memory:c0500000-c0503fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20u1
       serial: c6:b4:40:bb:52:e3
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.52 link=yes multicast=yes
```

I tried a fix based on missing firmware from here [Wifi not working on Thinkpad T460](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005167/wifi-not-working-on-thinkpad-t460)

But it threw errors

```
dpkg  -i linux-firmware*.deb
dpkg: warning: downgrading linux-firmware from 1.173.1 to 1.169.3
(Reading database ... 163898 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-firmware_1.169.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (1.169.3) over (1.173.1) ...
Setting up linux-firmware (1.169.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-24-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-23-generic

HP-ProBook-430-G2:~/Downloads$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
rmmod: ERROR: missing module name.
modprobe: FATAL: Error running remove command for iwlwifi
```

Any ideas please?