# ThinkPad T430u wifi not working

Tags: drivers, wireless, lenovo, thinkpad

This is a new installation (20.04) on a laptop I never used, I get:

> No wifi adapter found

There's an ETH connection, that also doesn't work, but that's less important. I can access internet wiring the ETH cable through a USB hub.

I looked up for help, this question looked promising but the link in it doesn't work.

[Wifi not working on Thinkpad T460](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005167/wifi-not-working-on-thinkpad-t460)

```
$ dmesg
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x21, date = 2019-02-13
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.8.0-48-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-008) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 13:40:25 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1-generic 5.8.18)
[    0.126879] Speculative Store Bypass: Mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
[    0.126883] SRBDS: Vulnerable: No microcode
[    0.126884] MDS: Mitigation: Clear CPU buffers
[    0.127179] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.133357] smpboot: CPU0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz (family: 0x6, model: 0x3a, stepping: 0x9)
[    0.133526] Performance Events: PEBS fmt1+, IvyBridge events, 16-deep LBR, full-width counters, Intel PMU driver.
[    0.133534] ... version:                3
[    0.133534] ... bit width:              48
[    0.133535] ... generic registers:      4
[    0.133536] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
[    0.133537] ... max period:             00007fffffffffff
[    0.133537] ... fixed-purpose events:   3
[    0.133538] ... event mask:             000000070000000f
[    0.133586] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.134939] NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.135062] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.135200] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.135202] .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1
[    0.137380] MDS CPU bug present and SMT on, data leak possible. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/hw-vuln/mds.html for more details.
[    0.137467]  #2 #3





[   12.733157] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[   12.736856] r8152 4-2.2:1.0 enx00143d0828d6: renamed from eth0
[   12.802505] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input17
[   12.802582] input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input18
[   12.802650] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input19
[   12.802715] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input20
[   12.893579] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[   12.893598] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21f3.hcd'
[   12.893599] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21f3.hcd'
[   13.098873] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20200528/nsarguments-59)
[   13.099139] pci 0000:01:00.0: optimus capabilities: enabled, status dynamic power, hda bios codec supported
[   13.099141] VGA switcheroo: detected Optimus DSM method \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP handle
[   13.099312] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: NVIDIA GF117 (0d7000a2)
[   13.172397] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[   13.180346] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bios: version 75.17.34.00.02
[   13.199443] b43-phy0: Broadcom 43228 WLAN found (core revision 30)
[   13.199875] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 9, Type 4 (N), Revision 16
[   13.199884] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2057, Revision 9, Version 1
[   13.200342] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   13.200355] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   13.200371] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   13.200382] b43 bcma0:1: Direct firmware load for b43-open/ucode30_mimo.fw failed with error -2
[   13.200383] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode30_mimo.fw" not found
[   13.200385] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode30_mimo.fw" not found
[   13.200386] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
[   13.200434] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]
[   13.269045] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb: 1024 MiB DDR3
[   13.316918] vga_switcheroo: enabled
[   13.316977] [TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 3996058 KiB
[   13.316978] [TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 KiB
[   13.316979] [TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[   13.316982] [TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[   13.316995] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: VRAM: 1024 MiB
[   13.316996] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: GART: 1048576 MiB
[   13.316999] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table not found
[   13.317000] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: DCB version 4.0
[   13.318041] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: MM: using COPY0 for buffer copies
[   13.318374] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.3.1 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   13.385916] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   13.594461] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[   13.594462] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[   13.594463] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[   13.594468] intel_rapl_common: RAPL package-0 domain package locked by BIOS
[   13.642660] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b327)
[   13.653007] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/input/input21
[   13.653081] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   13.653082] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   17.925119] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.261:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=704 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.928519] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.265:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ippusbxd" pid=702 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   17.938770] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.277:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=701 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.028552] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.365:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=710 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.032521] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.369:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=708 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.032526] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.369:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=708 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.032529] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.369:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party" pid=708 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.044931] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.381:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=709 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.044950] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.381:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=709 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   18.044954] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660959.381:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=709 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   23.288166] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.288167] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.288171] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   23.318484] NET: Registered protocol family 38
[   24.284413] kauditd_printk_skb: 25 callbacks suppressed
[   24.284414] audit: type=1400 audit(1616660965.621:37): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=823 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[   27.817554] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   28.288255] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx00143d0828d6: link becomes ready
[   28.288463] r8152 4-2.2:1.0 enx00143d0828d6: carrier on
[   31.877657] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[   35.474065] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   35.474071] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   35.474079] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   41.508524] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000691f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[   41.508544] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of badf1001 FAULT at 50405c [ IBUS ]
[   49.594461] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[   54.618156] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  267.322898] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[  267.431347] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of 0000691f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[  273.596065] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[  567.705809] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661509.419:38): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/10908/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2398 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  567.706755] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661509.423:39): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/core/10908/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=2398 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  567.901754] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661509.615:40): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.core" pid=2400 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  567.966926] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661509.683:41): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.core.hook.configure" pid=2401 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  606.765347] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661548.480:42): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.canonical-livepatch" pid=2523 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  606.844636] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661548.560:43): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd" pid=2525 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  606.884723] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661548.600:44): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.configure" pid=2526 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  606.886228] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661548.604:45): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch" pid=2524 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  609.774319] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661551.492:46): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2577 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[  612.559456] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661554.276:47): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/11036/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2736 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  612.559461] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661554.276:48): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/snap/snapd/11036/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=2736 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  612.584999] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661554.300:49): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.canonical-livepatch" pid=2738 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  612.703568] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661554.420:50): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.hook.configure" pid=2741 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  612.741276] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661554.456:51): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd" pid=2740 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  612.778369] audit: type=1400 audit(1616661554.496:52): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatch" pid=2739 comm="apparmor_parser"
[  612.878022] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Enabling HDA controller
[  612.979659] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of ffffff1f FAULT at 6013d4 [ IBUS ]
[  612.979680] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: bus: MMIO write of badf1001 FAULT at 50405c [ IBUS ]
[  618.770031] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[ 2774.850854] audit: type=1400 audit(1616663716.633:53): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=3905 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[ 2781.252300] audit: type=1326 audit(1616663723.033:54): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=2 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=3905 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/518/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7fc680126639 code=0x50000
[ 2781.601130] audit: type=1107 audit(1616663723.385:55): pid=743 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.16" pid=3905 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=744 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 2783.479531] audit: type=1107 audit(1616663725.261:56): pid=743 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=3905 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=754 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 2783.480186] audit: type=1107 audit(1616663725.261:57): pid=743 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=3905 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=754 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 2786.006292] audit: type=1400 audit(1616663727.789:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=3905 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 2786.035459] audit: type=1400 audit(1616663727.817:59): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gdm/greeter/applications/gnome-initial-setup.desktop" pid=3905 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[ 2786.570313] audit: type=1107 audit(1616663728.353:60): pid=743 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=3905 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=754 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 2786.570753] audit: type=1107 audit(1616663728.353:61): pid=743 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=3905 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=754 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[ 2787.050293] audit: type=1400 audit(1616663728.833:62): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf" pid=3905 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

The link suggested above at kernel.org is a 404.

```
sudo lshw

           *-network
                description: Network controller
                product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
                resources: irq:17 memory:f4600000-f4603fff
           *-network DISABLED
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
                logical name: enp9s0
                version: 07
                serial: 08:9e:01:19:ed:5f
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
                resources: irq:19 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f3c04000-f3c04fff memory:f3c00000-f3c03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@4:2.2
       logical name: enx00143d0828d6
       serial: 00:14:3d:08:28:d6
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.11.11 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153b-2 v1 10/23/19 ip=10.41.32.21 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

If this helps:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21f3 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:1002 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:b327 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Help is very welcome, thank you.

Comment: Please note: "Broadcom 43228 WLAN found" Next, follow the precedure outlined at the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you - the procedure worked very well (though I couldn't manage to test the wifi in infrastructure or ad-hoc)